Who is "Baby" here?
Adam Warlock, in his pursuit of Rocket, rips off Groot's head
to stop Groot from preventing him. Meanwhile, Kraglin, who
is hiding, uses his power to throw a Yaka Arrow at Adam Warlock:

Adam Warlock: Who threw this thing at me? Baby.

Who is "Baby" here?

The person who threw the thing (it's not a term of endearment). Seriously, had you thought of joining our [ell.se] site, you may find it very useful.

@JiminyCricket. This question better suited here than there. See this

"Acceptable to ask here" - yes. "Better suited here" - not really...

@SamoeP: this one isn't, because there's nothing specific about sci-fi or fantasy in the phrase in question. (Although I understand it can be difficult to make that call while you're still learning the language.)

@fez - It's both on-topic and answerable. What more could we ask for?

@SamoeP I'm happy for it to be here, my comment wasn't to suggest otherwise. I seriously think the OP would benefit from membership on [ELL.se], as I've suggested to them on a couple of previous occasions.

In this context Adam is expressing frustration at being 'pinged' by the Yaka Arrow. He doesn't seem to realise that it's supposed to be a deadly weapon since his skin is near-impervious. It's just an annoyance to him.
He's asking who was childish enough to throw a pointy stick. When they don't immediately reveal themselves (so he can kill them) he insults them, sotto voce, calling them a baby;

an adult who behaves like a child; an immature, helpless, or fearful person

